# Javascript rounding to two decimal places

Tags: javascript

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Round to 2 Decimal Places</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('input#txtNum').blur(function() {
                var amt = parseFloat(this.value);
                //$(this).val('$' + amt.toFixed(2));
                $(this).val((Math.round(amt*100))/100).toFixed(2);
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Type a decimal number in the TextBox and hit Tab
    <br />
    <input id="txtNum" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

when i am entering value as 100.2569.The result shows 100.26 but when i am entering 56.999 its showing 57 instead of 57.00 or if i am giving value without decimal its showing without decimals without two appending two zeroes after decimal.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `toFixed` in the wrong place:

```
$(this).val( (Math.round(amt*100)/100).toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: this is done using jQuery. can this be done using only Javascript only?

Comment: @shiva The jQuery isn't too far from vanilla JavaScript. Rather than `$(this).val()` you would simply assign the results to `this.value`. What browser-support do you need? While more modern browsers support `addEventListener`,  you'd have to fallback to `attachEvent` when it's present, and further back to modifying element members directly when neither are present.

Comment: I think `(Math.round(amt*100)/100).toFixed(2)` can be simplified to `amt.toFixed(2)`.

Answer (score 3):

It is more simple than you think:

```
amt.toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Javascript as follows:

```
this.value = (Math.round(amt*100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

If it is a single text input:

```
document.getElementById("txtNum").value = (Math.round(amt*100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: It looks like the code is not working as expected. There is an extra `)` which produces a SyntaxError. The `(amt*100)/100` part is the same as `amt`.

Comment: @cbliard : The code "Math.round((amt*100)/100).toFixed(2)" is picked up from the question. Hence, I din't check what it does.

Comment: Note quite: the original code is `(Math.round(amt*100)/100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @cbliard : Noted and incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below works, too.

```
ProperRoundCircle = function(num, decimal){ 
 return Math.round(parseFloat(Number) * Math.pow(10, decimal)) / Math.pow(10, decimal);
}
```